# Informix grammar explanation？What does the grammar in the picture mean？

Tags: informix

[A fragment of SQL in the Informix dialect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1UUB.png)

```
SELECT INSUREDNAME
  FROM sc5100car3gdb@idp_5100_cb:PRPCINSURED P
 WHERE P.PROPOSALNO = A.PROPOSALNO
```

What does this grammar mean?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL fragment is:

```
SELECT INSUREDNAME
  FROM sc5100car3gdb@idp_5100_cb:PRPCINSURED P
 WHERE P.PROPOSALNO = A.PROPOSALNO
```

This means that there is a table `PRPCINSURED` in database `sc5100car3gdb` hosted on Informix server `idp_5100_cb`; inside the query, the table will be referred to by the alias `P`.  It has columns `INSUREDNAME` and `PROPOSALNO`.  Further, this must be a fragment of an SQL statement.  The WHERE clause uses the alias `P`, but also references another table with the alias (or perhaps name) `A`.  However, the context defining `A` is not shown; as it stands, the `A` will trigger an error.  (When I ran an analogous query, I got the error `SQL -217: Column (a) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined)`.)

See the Informix Guide to SQL: Syntax manual on [database object names](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10/14.10?topic=segments-database-object-name) for more information about the notation used for the table name.